# Service Worker and transparent cache updates

Tags: service-worker

I am trying to install a ServiceWorker for a simple, yet old, Django web app. I started working with the example [read-through caching example from the Chrome team](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/service-worker/read-through-caching/index.html)

This works well but isn't ideal because I want to update the cache, if needed. There are two recommended ways to do this based on reading all the other service-worker answers here.

1. Use some server-side logic to know when the stuff you show has updated and then update your service worker to change what is precached. This is what sw-precache does, for example.
2. Just update the cache version in the service worker JS file (see comments in the JS file on the caching example above) whenever resources you depend on update.

Neither are great solutions for me. First, this is a dumb, legacy app. I don't have the application stack that sw-precache relies on. Second, someone else updates the data that will be shown (it is basically a list of things with a details page).

I wanted to try out the "use cache, but update the cache from network" that Jake Archibald suggested in his [offline cookbook](https://jakearchibald.com/2014/offline-cookbook/#cache-then-network) but I can't quite get it to work.

My original thinking was I should just be able to return the cached version in my service worker, but queue a function that would update the cache if the network is available. For example, something like this in the fetch event listener

```
// If there is an entry in cache, return it after queueing an update
console.log(' Found response in cache:', response);
setTimeout(function(request, cache){
    fetch(request).then(function(response){
        if (response.status < 400 && response.type == 'basic') {
            console.log("putting a new response into cache");
            cache.put(request, response);
        }   
    })  
},10, request.clone(), cache);

return response;
```

But this doesn't work. The page gets stuck loading.

whats wrong with the code above? Whats the right way to get to my target design?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like https://jakearchibald.com/2014/offline-cookbook/#stale-while-revalidate is very close to what you're looking for

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.open('mysite-dynamic').then(function(cache) {
      return cache.match(event.request).then(function(response) {
        var fetchPromise = fetch(event.request).then(function(networkResponse) {
          // if we got a response from the cache, update the cache
          if (response) {
            cache.put(event.request, networkResponse.clone());
          }
          return networkResponse;
        });

        // respond from the cache, or the network
        return response || fetchPromise;
      });
    })
  );
});
```

Comment: Hmm .. not quite, because, if I am not wrong, this will still hit the network first. So, for a slow network, it will take a long time and then return the network response (which in all likelihood is the same as the cached response). This will be offline, but not fast.

Comment: Nope, the cache response does not wait for the network request, so you'll get an instant response if it's cached

Comment: aah .. so if the response is null only then the fetchPromise is resolved?

Comment: Technically it's undefined rather than null, but yeah. Well, fetchPromise will always resolve, but the browser won't wait on it to display the cached content.

Comment: sorry for the delay! I got excited and started playing with it right away.

Comment: You can activate the new service worker immediately, [see this](https://davidwalsh.name/service-worker-claim)

Answer (score 0):

On page reload you can refresh your service worker with new version meanwhile old one will take care of request.

Once everything is done and no page is using old service worker, It will using newer version of service worker.

```
this.addEventListener('fetch', function(event){
    event.responseWith(
        caches.match(event.request).then(function(response){
            return response || fetch(event.request).then(function(resp){
                return caches.open('v1').then(function(cache){
                    cache.put(event.request, resp.clone());
                    return resp;
                })
            }).catch(function() {
                return caches.match('/sw/images/myLittleVader.jpg');
            });
        })
    )
});
```

I recommend you to walk through below link for detailed functionality

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers