# Service Worker throws uncaught errors when the server is down

Tags: caching, service-worker

I am using the caching facility of service workers, however, after an update to the site, the cache still serves the old data when I refresh the page.

So as per the answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33590734/service-worker-and-transparent-cache-updates) I implemented the stale-while-revalidate:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    event.respondWith(caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then(function(cache) {
        return cache.match(event.request).then(function(response) {
            var fetchPromise = fetch(event.request).then(function(networkResponse) {
                // if we got a response from the cache, update the cache
                if (response) {
                    console.log("cached page: " + event.request.url);
                    cache.put(event.request, networkResponse.clone());
                }
                return networkResponse;
            });

            // respond from the cache, or the network
            return response || fetchPromise;
        });
    }));
});
```

While connected, all seems well, and I can see the console log message.

When I stop the server and refresh the page I get a load of exceptions.

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I added a catch on the fetch() to try and handle the exceptions but it still fails (and the catch is not called). I added a catch on the caches.open() and respondWith() but same thing.

I know I *can* ignore these errors, but I'd rather handle them and do nothing (including not outputing them to the console) so I can see the meaningful stuff in the console I am outputting.

How can I stop the error messages?

The error when the service installs is less of a probem, but that would also be nice to catch and ignore.

Answer (score 1):

Adding in a no-op `.catch()` to the end of your `fetch()` promise chain should prevent the `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch` message from being logged:

```
var fetchPromise = fetch(event.request).then(function(networkResponse) {
    // if we got a response from the cache, update the cache
    if (response) {
      console.log("cached page: " + event.request.url);
      cache.put(event.request, networkResponse.clone());
    }
    return networkResponse;
}).catch(function() {
  // Do nothing.
});
```

I know you mentioned that you tried to add in a `.catch()`, but perhaps it wasn't located on the correct part of the chain?

I'm not aware of any way to prevent the `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` message from being logged, as that comes directly from Chrome's native networking code. There's nothing you could "handle" from JavaScript.

Comment: Yep, it seems to be the consensus that you cannot hide the network state alerts :( The catch still didn't work but I did get it working. See my final code. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I did put the catch where you had it, I even tried again, but still errors. The key turned out to be a second function to the then() call.

This was the eventually working code. There was also a bug in the initial response handling from the post I cut and paste. This one works for me.

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    event.respondWith(caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then(function(cache) {
        return cache.match(event.request).then(function(response) {
            //console.log("cache request: " + event.request.url);
            var fetchPromise = fetch(event.request).then(function(networkResponse) {
                // if we got a response from the cache, update the cache
                //console.log("fetch completed: " + event.request.url, networkResponse);
                if (networkResponse) {
                    //console.debug("updated cached page: " + event.request.url, networkResponse);
                    cache.put(event.request, networkResponse.clone());
                }
                return networkResponse;
            }, function (e) {
                // rejected promise - just ignore it, we're offline
                //console.log("Error in fetch()", e);
                ;
            });

            // respond from the cache, or the network
            return response || fetchPromise;
        });
    }));
});
```